# SQL dense ranking function

Tags: sql, ranking-functions

I have a table called employees, with `'employee_id'` and `'bonuses'` as columns. The **employee_id's** are repeated because **they have multiple bonuses of different amounts**, and I want to rank them by their total bonus amount.

So, I was wondering if this would be the correct way to rank the employees by their total bonus amount descending:

```
SELECT employee_id, SUM(bonuses) AS total_bonus, DENSE_RANK(ORDER BY total_bonus DESC) AS bonus_rank
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

My desired output is a table with the `employee_id` only listed once, the corresponding `total bonus amount the employee received`, and the `rank of bonuses starting from rank #1 with the highest total bonus amount`.

Comment: Provide some sample data of your case and the expected result from that sample.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the computed Bonus value in the ORDER BY clause - no need to bother with dense ranks.

```
SELECT employee_id, SUM(bonuses) AS total_bonus
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY SUM(bonuses) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your query except that your are attempting to use an alias `total_bonus` in the `DENSE_RANK()` function at the same level of a `SELECT`.  This can't be done, AFAIK, because the alias won't yet be avaiable.  Instead, just use the `SUM()` term again:

```
SELECT employee_id,
       SUM(bonuses) AS total_bonus,
       DENSE_RANK(ORDER BY SUM(bonuses) DESC) AS bonus_rank
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee_id;
```